# Is reindex needed if we restore search service application to backup environment

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, enterprise-search

We have search service application running with 11 Million items on the two search servers in live environment.

We have to maintain the same search application in DR environment as well, so we are planing to use Restore-SearchServiceApplication command with powershell.

This will take the complete index backup. So we believe, we can directly restore this search service back to DR server so that search service is available in DR servers.

Please let us know whether re indexing needed again post restoration of search application in DR server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to reset index because if you have to then what is purpose of search service application restore.

> If you can, you should perform a backup and restore of your Search
>   service application instead of a search index reset. These procedures
>   will fully restore all features that are powered by the Analytics
>   Processing Component

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219652(v=office.16).aspx

Please follow this article for restore of search service application.

[Restore Search service applications in SharePoint Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748654(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do reindex. Using PowerShell backs up all of the search components including the databases, the search service configuration, and all of the index files.

The search index files are always fully backed up, even when you use the Differential option.

Reference:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748635.aspx